# When does cohomology take pullbacks to pushouts?

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I've encountered a simple situation where one has a pullback diagram of topological spaces and taking cohomology takes it into what I believe is a pushout diagram in the category of rings. I'm not sure if I can make diagrams here, but I have maps $X \overset{f}\to Z \overset{g}\leftarrow Y$
and the fiber product $$X \times_Z Y = \big\{(x,y) \in X \times Y : f(x) = g(y)\big\}$$ given the subspace topology. When I take singular cohomology with rational coefficients, in this case, I get an isomorphism
$$H^*(X \times_Z Y) \cong H^*(X) \otimes_{H^*(Z)} H^*(Y),$$
where the $H^*(Z)$-algebra structures on $H^*(X)$ and $H^*(Y)$ are given by pullback along $f$ and $g$.

**How general is this situation?** 
**What needs to go right for it to work?** What needs to go wrong for it to fail?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Moore_spectral_sequence

Comment: I found that article (again, incidentally) about ten minutes after posting my question, and felt very unresourceful.

Comment: I have very little idea how to compute the double-subscripted Tor, which seems kind of daunting. Is that worth posting another question about?

Comment: The double-graded Tor is not as bad as it sounds.  You still compute Tor the same way (using a projective resolution), but since your ring and modules are graded the resolution can inherit its own grading too.  It's worth trying a couple of examples (e.g. $S^1 = S^3 \times_{S^2} *$ for the Hopf fibration) to get a feel forhow the grading goes.

Answer (score 3):

Well, your question is exactly what motivates people to study homotopy theory. I would advise you to look at Model Category Theory.

To answer your question, I think it always works when $f$ or $g$ is a fibration (and if your ring of coefficents is a field).

Let me also give you a counterexample. Let $X$ and $Y$ be points, $Z$ be the closed interval, and $f$ and $g$ be the inclusions on $0$ and $1$.
Then the fiber product is empty… (The right thing to do here would have been to take the homotopy fiber product).
But $f$ and $g$ are homotopy equivalences, so $H^\ast(X) \simeq H^\ast(Z) \simeq H^\ast(Y)$.

Comment: So what is the homotopy fiber product?

In my trivial examples, $f$ is a fibration (actually, $g$ is too), the fiber is ``totally nonhomologous to zero,'' if I'm using that term right, and the Serre spectral sequence for $X \times Y \to Y$ collapses at $E_2$. Books seem to be telling me that the Eilenberg&ndash;Moore spectral sequence breaks down in that case. I'm kind of wondering how much room I have.

Comment: I've seen it claimed elsewhere, too, that if $f$ or $g$ is a fibration, the EMSS breaks down at $E_2$: do you know of any citations for this?

Comment: @jdc Do you remember where you read that claim?

Comment: @Dog_69: No, but I assume I must have misinterpreted something, maybe missed an implicit condition in some remark. I don't believe it is true in general.

Comment: @jdc Okay, thank you for replying.