# Reference request: where can I find illustrative, concrete examples of the use of the Eilenberg–Moore spectral sequence?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

Pursuant to advice at [When does cohomology take pullbacks to pushouts?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/682766/when-does-cohomology-take-pullbacks-to-pushouts), I tried to use the Eilenberg–Moore spectral sequence in the simplest conceivable example, for the Hopf bundle $S^3 \to S^2$. It did not go well. I decided I didn't understand $\mathrm{Tor}_{*,*}$ at all, so I asked an algebraist. We went through the computation and successfully proved that $H^*(S^1)$ is infinite-dimensional. That was dispiriting.

So I seem to need some help. Where can I see something like this worked out to get the gist of how to use this sequence?